# If an improper integral equals some value L, does that imply it is divergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I worked out $\int _1^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{4x+5}}{x^2}\:dx$ to have an undefined limit, which tells me it diverges. I'm still trying to fully understand improper integrals so somebody correct me if this integral doesn't diverge.

I wanted to ask, if an improper integral equals some value L, does that imply it converges?

Edit: How do you use the direct comparison test to confirm whether my improper integral actually diverges?

Comment: Yes, it converges to the value it equals

Comment: @DavidRaveh thanks. I'm not sure if my improper integral I put in the question actually diverges now I think about it. I tried using the direct comparison test but I'm confused on what way round the implications go when using the comparable function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is "yes." That's what convergence means.

With experience, you'd look at your integrand and sort of blur out the constants and think "that's about $\sqrt{x}/x^2 = 1/x^{3/2}$ and the integral of that converges, so my original integral converges."

Then to prove it with the direct comparison test, you'd try to find a multiple of $1/x^{3/2}$ that is larger than your integrand.  Something like:

$$\frac{\sqrt{4x+5}}{x^2} < \frac{\sqrt{10x}}{x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{x^{3/2}}$$

since for $x\geq 1$ you have $10x \geq 4x+5.$

Because $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{10}}{x^{3/2}} \; dx$$

converges, so does your original integral.

Comment: I like the idea of blurring out the constants thanks. I orginally compared it to $1/x^2$ but that didn't do anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If an improper indefinite integral equals to some value or rather expression $L$ then it does not necessarily mean that after putting the limits you'll get a value.

In your case, first evaluate the indefinite integral of the same.  It is equal to $$-\dfrac{2\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{4x+5}+\sqrt{5}\right)-\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{4x+5}-\sqrt{5}\right|\right)\right)}{\sqrt{5}}-\dfrac{\sqrt{4x+5}}{x}$$
Now when you'll put the limits $1,\infty$ you'll get the following result $$3-\dfrac{2\ln\left(-\frac{3\sqrt{5}-7}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{5}}$$

But try putting the limits $0,\infty$ then you'll see that you can't put the limits as the integral will behave divergent in this case.